# Regex.IsMatch returning true when it should not

Tags: c#, regex

**Regex Pattern**

```
patternMatch = "^(?i)/(A|B)?(?:/index.html|/|)"
```

**Input String** -

```
inputString = "/_Test/C.asmx"
```

`(Regex.IsMatch(inputString, patternMatch, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))` returns true, when it should return false.

Now, I get it that the double '?' in the regex pattern isn't required. But, I am just trying to find out why the pattern match is failing.

http://www.regexr.com/ tells me it should return false.

Comment: It matches because of the or: `|`.. also.. Regexr does match it. It matches the first forward slash.

Comment: Yeah, regexr does not match it. It shouldn't. But, in .net Regex.IsMatch returns true.

Comment: How come or: | is interfering with the pattern match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have meant this regex instead:

```
patternMatch = @"^(?i)/(A|B)?(?:/index\.html|/|)$"
```

`@` is to raw the regex string.

`\.` is to escape the dot so that a literal dot (and not any character) is matched.

`$` is to match the end of the string and to ensure that the regex attempts to match the whole string.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. Sorry my question wasn't clear enough - my main concern is that in .NET, this Regex passes and in `regexr.com`, which I believe is .NET regex tester didn't? Is there a way to make these regex entries .NET compatible before doing the comparison (the Regex entries are manually fed in the system, so there is a scope for errors).

Comment: @NomadTraveler Okay, I'll try to address your problems, but I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for. regexr is a JavaScript based regex tester, not a .NET. The best .NET regex tester I know is regexhero.net. Then, [regexr is telling you your regex returns true](http://regexr.com?38i7i). As long as there's any part of the input highlighted, there is a match. Maybe it's clearer on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/rT1iA5) which is not a .NET based regex tester but supports more .NET features than regexr.

Comment: And what do you mean you want to make the regex .NET compatible? This sounds like a tough job that only the person entering these regex would know whether the regex they enter are .NET compatible or not. What are you looking for exactly? Like something to convert any non-compatible regex into a .NET compatible regex?

Comment: I thought the whole input string was to be highlighted, if it was a match in `Regexr`? `Regex101` looks good though. Yes, the idea is to make the regex .NET compatible before testing if it matches the input string. Like for example, if I get rid of `$` from your regex, then the regex matches with the input string `/_Test/C.asmx`?

Comment: @NomadTraveler Well, I'm not sure what sort of solution you're looking for. As I said, it would be best if the user is knowledgeable about the subject. And [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester) is exclusively for .NET. The full features (copy/paste, linking) are not free unfortunately, but you can still test for free. It tells you of the number of matches, for instance in this [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WahCv.png). I think that your original question has been 'answered' though, because your regex is supposed to return true and regexr agrees with this. You just misinterpreted it.